# Name инпута в value чекбокса, PHP.

Tags: php, html, css

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста, хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь выбирая товар на сайте просто ставил галку в чекбоксе и рядом вписывал в инпут количество этого товара и в конце концов когда всё выберет и выставит количество отправлял в таблицу но у меня не очень получается помогите пожалуйста.

```
<div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input  type="checkbox" class="form" name="order[]" value="245, <?php $amount1 ?>"> // тут по всякому пробовал и что то никак
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount1" placeholder="Кол-во" style="width: 5em;">
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Пробовал через форму и $_GET но тоже не получилось, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы отправить форму нужно хотя бы создать саму форму. А вообще если вы не понимаете чего-то попробуйте заглянуть в [справочник](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form). Там можно найти описание тега form и его атрибутов, именно то что вам нужно знать для сего задания.

```html
<form method="POST">
   <p><input type="checkbox">
   <input type="text"></p>
   <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```